# Post a value from form using javascript then postin with php

Tags: php, javascript, uploadify

I'm trying to do is insert some information into a database, my first page is this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //alert('I am ready to use uploadify!');
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'uploader': 'uploadifyit/uploadify.swf',
        'script': 'uploadifyit/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg': 'uploadifyit/cancel.png',
        'folder': 'images',
        'auto': false, // use for auto upload
        'multi': true,
        'queueSizeLimit': 4,
        'onQueueFull': function(event, queueSizeLimit) {
            alert("Please don't put anymore files in me! You can upload " + queueSizeLimit + " files at once");
            return false;
        },
        'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
            // you can use here jQuery AJAX method to send info at server-side.
            $.post("insert.php", { name: fileObj.name }, function(info) {
                alert(info); // alert UPLOADED FILE NAME
            });
        }
    });



});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$img_id=$_REQUEST['img_id'];
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="">
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" /><br />
<input type="hidden" value="<? echo $img_id ;?>" name="image_id"  />

<a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();">Upload File</a>
</form>
```

While the processing form is:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {

        //echo $_POST['name'];
        $fileName = $_POST['name'];
        $id = $_REQUEST['image_id'];


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_images(img_file,img_gal_id) VALUES('$fileName','$id')");
        $inserted_id = mysql_insert_id($dbc);

        if($inserted_id > 0) { // if success
            echo "uploaded file: " . $fileName;
        }

    }
```

I can post the $fileName but not the $id.

Comment: How about add the ID here ? `$.post("insert.php", { name: fileObj.name }` -> `$.post("insert.php", { name: fileObj.name,image_id:ID }`

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com)... enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Hey sofl... thanks, wel i probably should change this lines image_id:ID , i mean, what values is supposed ID to be?..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `POST` instead of `REQUEST` in your processing form, and pass the `image_id` value in with the JSON as soft/MMK recommended. You can save yourself the hidden field and variable declaration and inject the value into the `$.post`:

```
$.post("insert.php", 
  { 
    name: fileObj.name, 
    // Add the image_id value to post to insert.php
    image_id: <?php echo $_REQUEST['img_id']; ?> 
  ...
```

Then in processing:

```
$fileName = $_POST['name'];
// Grab the posted value.
$id = $_POST['image_id'];
```

Comment: In terms of Marc B's comment, it is obviously expected that you would do some value validation -- I suppose a simple [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) would suffice, if your `img_gal_id` field is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
        // you can use here jQuery AJAX method to send info at server-side.
        $.post("insert.php", { name: fileObj.name,image_id:ID}, function(info) {
            alert(info); // alert UPLOADED FILE NAME
        });
    }
```

Comment: hmm it still won't work... maybe sorry for the studpid question and all the rest but, maybe i should rename the variable in the other php file then?

Comment: I guess i'm doing something wrong with the names.. with the form! can you please check it?